# Formula of subtotals

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I manually created the cumulative subtotals in column H. .these are correct. However, I would like to know the formula that can return these values instead of manually manipulating the numbers.

Comment: You need to hide those rows? And, those hidden rows should not be taken into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

I am making some assumptions here.

You have hidden rows and and you want to exclude numbers in those hidden rows.
According to your picture your start row will be H13 and I am assuming it will go until H100... but you can change that H100 to any rows of your need.

Please use the following formula to H13 and pull down.

```
=AGGREGATE(9,5,$G$13:G100)
```

Make sure you change G100 to your appropriate row number.

9 and 5 used in the formula are constants and you don't need to change for this case. Where 9 represents "SUM" and 5 represents "Ignore hidden rows"

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, according to your formula there is difference in value.

Comment: please see image in above post

Comment: Looks like your calculation is wrong.
How did you get 68.75 by adding 63.65 and 4.76? If you add 63.65 and 4.76, it would be 68.41. So, the formula is correctly calculating.